# Three tables, One logic and Nine numbers to guess

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

Here is a table divided in three parts, the first two (the green and the yellow ones) are completely clear, while the last one (which is red) has 9 numbers to guess (**α1**, **β1**, **γ1**, **δ1**, **α2**, **β2**, **γ2**, **δ2** and, most important, **?**), gettable by a logic that is the same for every table part.

How hard will it be to find the missing numbers and the logic? Let's discover it together!

[image: The tables]

Good luck!

---

Transcription

Green section:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **a** | 7 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 6 |
| **b** | 1 | 5 | 0 | 9 | 3 |
| **c** | - | 3 | 10 | 1 | + |
| **d** | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 |
| **e** | 2 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 4 |

Yellow section:

|  | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **a** | 1 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 3 |
| **b** | 7 | 2 | 8 | 0 | 9 |
| **c** | + | 3 | 5 | 4 | - |
| **d** | 4 | 1 | 9 | 0 | 6 |
| **e** | 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 5 |

Red section:

|  | K | L | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **a** | 2 | 7 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| **b** | 1 | 5 | 8 | 0 | 9 |
| **c** | + | 3 | ? | 0 | - |
| **d** | α1 | β1 | 7 | γ1 | δ1 |
| **e** | α2 | β2 | 8 | γ2 | δ2 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bottom rows of the red grid are

> **5,7**,7,**3,9,1,8**,8,**3,9**

because the bottom rows of each grid are obtained by

> reading the top rows in the usual order and alternating between the two operations in the middle (left, right, left, right,...)

I suspect that the middle numbers are

> the opposite of the total change: five applications each of -3 and +1 make the opposite of 10, five applications each of +3 and -4 make the opposite of 5, and five applications each of +3 and -0 make the opposite of **-15**.

Comment: The answer is correct, the only thing I haven't thought of is the minus before the last central value, because when I created that, I thought it as the difference between above values with the under ones, which is the exactly value you can obtain doing an algebrical sum with the central values multiplied by 5 (except the one in the middle)